# Problema de For

Tags: c++, bucle-for

estoy intentando hacer un cuadrado vacío en C++; Al momento de hacer los espacios se rompe la cadena de asteriscos

```
main()
{
   int a,i;
   scanf("%i", &a);
   for (i = 1; i <= a; ++i)
   {
       printf("*");
   }
   printf("\n");
   for (i=1; i<=(a-2);++i)
   {
       printf("*");
       for (i=1; i<=(a-2);++i)
       {
       printf(" ");
       
       }
       printf("*");
   }
   printf("\n");
   for (i = 1; i <= a; ++i)
   {
       printf("*");
   }
}
```

Ejemplo si dígito el numero 4 debería estar así:

```
****
*  *
*  *
****
```

He intentado con diferentes saltos de línea, cambiar algunos for por un do-while y cosas asi

Answer (score 0):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   int a,i,j;
   scanf("%i", &a);
   
   for (i = 1; i <= a; ++i)
   {
       printf("*");
   }
   printf("\n");
   
   
   for (i=1; i<=(a-2);++i)
   {
       printf("*");
       for (j=1; j<=(a-2);++j)
       {
       printf(" ");
       
       }
       printf("*\n");
   }
   
   for (i = 1; i <= a; ++i)
   {
       printf("*");
   }
}
```

Esta sería la forma correcta, tu problema era en utilizar la variable i para el for anidado ya que sobre escribía el valor del for padre, también debes de cambiar el ultimo salto de linea.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, el error es que tienes un for anidado en el cual utilizas "i" en ambos y cuando entra al for interno esta se incrementa la cantidad de veces que este hace las repeticiones y cuando sale del for interno "i" tiene un valor mucho mayor que "a" por lo que se sale del ciclo y no continua escribiendo asteriscos. Intenta con utilizar otra variable si ya usaste "i". Espero te sirva.